# Настройка xstartup сервера TightVnc - не загружает среду рабочего стола xfce

Tags: xubuntu

У меня настроен Ubuntu Server 14, на нем установлен пакет

**xubuntu-desktop
xfce
cairo-dock**

Установлен **tightvnc** - настроен в автозапуск

Если я в файле **xstartup** указываю

```
  export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE=C
export LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL=

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xfce4-panel &
xsetroot -solid grey
gnome-terminal &
cairo-dock -o
```

То запускается сервер , а при подключении к нему я только вижу панель **cairo-dock** , где порой не видно названия программ при запуске значка
 **xfce4-panel** - вообще запускается как серый прямоугольник который нужно настраивать каждый раз при подключении, при этом все надписи на английском

если файл **xStartup** указать вот так

Load X resources (if any)
[ -e "${HOME}/.Xresources" ] \
    && xrdb "${HOME}/.Xresources"

Команда 
 сообщает фреймворку графического 
интерфейса 
пользователя VNC, что необходимо 
использовать 
пользовательский файл .Xresources.
Файл **.Xresources** сохраняет определённые пользовательские настройки рабочего стола, 
например, цвета терминала, 
тему курсора, рендеринг шрифтов.
**.Xresources**  файл, где пользователь может вносить изменения в 
определенные параметры графического рабочего стола, 
как цвет терминала, курсор темы, и рендеринг шрифтов.

startxfce4 &

эта команда просто сообщает серверу - запуск XFCE, 
в котором вы найдете все графическое программное обеспечение,
которое вам нужно, чтобы комфортно управлять сервером.

или вот так

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &

Тогда vncserver не запускается вообще.
Ему не нравится строка

**startxfce4 &**

А почему ?

А почему ?

Файл .Xresources  - вообще отсутствует, про него в интернете не нашел информацию, применяется ли он вообще, может он устарел и мануалы по настройке просто копирует этот код, нигде нет пояснения почему именно так нужно оформить xstartup.

Я же поставил графическую оболочку и локально подключаюсь и нет никаких проблем с раскладкой с языком или оформлением, так почему же нельзя и удаленно подключившись получить такие настройки ?
  Как нужно настроить конфигурационные файлы ?
было сообщение об отказе доступа в каталог **/home/alex/.config/xfce4**

Выполнил команду

sudo chown -R alex:alex /home/alex/.config/xfce4